# Missing Textbox text when exporting to pdf but present in printpreview and form view?

Tags: vba, ms-access

I have a report that is being generated and populates textboxes in the report accordingly. All the textboxes have the appropriate text in them when in form view and when i look at them under print preview, however when i use the following vba to export the report to pdf, certain fields are blank:

```
Dim sampleid As String
Dim exportpath As String
Dim fullpath As String

sampleid = Me.LabID.Value
exportpath = "C:\Users\me\Desktop\"
fullpath = exportpath & sampleid & "_Invoice" & ".pdf"

DoCmd.OutputTo acOutputReport, "InvoiceReport", acFormatPDF, fullpath
```

This is basically an invoice report and the missing fields are contained in a separate subform and are:

- GST (unbound textbox with a default value of 0.05 and format set to percentage)
- Tax (unbound textbox with content source set to
  =[subtotalprice]*[tax] and format set to currency, subtotalprice is also unbound with content source set to =Sum([Price]) which sums the
  Price textboxes in the continuous form above it (these fields are all
  in the footer)
- Paid amount (unbound but gets populated from an input box, format set to currency)
- Discount (same as the paid amount)
- Total (unbound textbox with content source set to
  =([subtotalprice]+[taxamount]+[wastefee])-Nz([paid]+[discount]) and format set to currency)

I've tried remaking the boxes in separate locations but theyre still blank once i export them, ive tried using the built in report buttons for exporting to pdf which causes them to still be blank, ive changed the font, resized the boxes and i have no clue why these arent showing up, i appreciate any help

Edit: ive noticed that if i close the form after generating from my main form and reopen in from the sidebar, the textbox text is visible when i re-export it, could it be possibly due to a timing issue or something?

Comment: This is a design issue, there is no code at fault to analyze so question not really appropriate for SO. Might want to post in a forum that allows attaching files and provide db for analysis. Do these controls use a different font than other elements of report?

Comment: @June7 No all of them are the same font and size, ive tried remaking the boxes from the beginning but it still doesnt print them out, ive also tried using pdfcreator to create the pdfs but it too cant print them out, i just dont get why its those specific boxes and the fact that they all have the exact same formatting

Answer (score 0):

Okay so posting for anyone else who struggles with this in the future, the problem was in the way i had the tax being calculated, instead of using the default value of 0.05 for GST, i added it to the contentsource as =0.05 which worked